# NGINX If -e to try_files

Tags: nginx

I have read [Pitfalls](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/) and [IfIsEvil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) and now want to try to have my full nginx config without ifs.

But I am not able to convert this additional PHP Rule:

```
if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(php|js|css|png|jpg|gif|gzip)$ /$1.$3 last;
}
```

Is someone able to help me? =(.

Have a nice day,

Bastian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
try_files $uri @rewrite_location
location @rewrite_location {
   .... your rewrite here
}
```